# Check direction of linestring against corresponding polygon using SpatiaLite

Tags: spatialite, direction

I have a polygon and a linestring that is part of the polygons boundary, but not necessarily digitized in the same direction as shown here:

[image]

In this case the linestring runs in the opposite direction of the polygons boundary.

How can I check if the linestring has the same direction or not using SpatiaLite?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution tested with spatialite would be

```
ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(theline.geom, thepoly.geom), theline.geom)
```

`ST_Intersection` return the portion of the polygons boundary the coincides with the linestring. In spatialite `ST_Equals` seems to return true if even the point ordering equals, in PostGIS `ST_Equals` is apparently more lenient, here `ST_OrderingEquals` must be used instead.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html

https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html